# Vertical alignment of table cell element in Firefox doesn't work

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jsp, firefox

I have to align a text cell to an image cell in a JSP file.
The jsp fragment is:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <arch:fondoListerGridItem serie="${serie}" fondo="${fondoPageData}" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <div style="display: table;position: absolute;height: 33%;width: 100%;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>
            <b><spring:theme code="text.fondo" />:</b> ${fondoPageData.fondo}<br>
            <b><spring:theme code="text.serie" />:</b> ${serie.titolo}
        </p>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome and IE browsers the result is this:

[image]

with the image and the text aligned in the middle of the table.

In Firefox instead the result is:
[image]

and the text is aligned on the top.
I saw from the developer consolle that the solution could be:

```
<div style="display: table;position: relative;height: 33%;width: 100%;">
<div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
```

for Chrome and IE, but

```
<div style="display: table;position: relative;height: 33%;width: 100%;">
<div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: bottom;">
```

for Firefox.
How could I do this in the JSP file?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Also, does Firefox really display different texts than Chrome?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5wwyevLd/

Comment: The fiddle looks the same in both browsers, which is unlike either of the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved replacing

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

with

```
padding-top: 50%;
```

This works on both browsers!